# Finding limit of sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have to find the limit of sequence ${a_{n}}$ such that 
$${a_{n}} = \frac {n^\frac{2}{3} \sin(e^n)} {n+1}$$

I have no idea where to start. Any hints on where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Squeeze Rule

and

$$ | \sin \alpha | \leq 1 $$

for all $\alpha $

Answer (score 0):

$$|{a_{n}}| = |\frac {n^\frac{2}{3} \sin(e^n)} {n+1}|\leq |\frac {n^\frac{2}{3}  }{n+1}|\to 0$$